# Minizinc - calculate Cost in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, constraint-programming, minizinc

In my model I've got `array[1..num_compute_nodes,1..num_access_nodes,1..num_request] of var 0..10: assignment;` and `array[1..num_compute_nodes,1..num_compute_nodes] of int: compute_nodes_relation`. First (decision) variable that I mentioned can look like that after running the model (it's after divide values by 10):

```
Compute node1: 
Access node1: 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
Access node2: 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 
Access node3: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,

Compute node2: 
Access node1: 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 
Access node2: 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
Access node3: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 

Compute node3: 
Access node1: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
Access node2: 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
Access node3: 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0,
```

**PROBLEM:** I want to calculate `var float: COST` - if something is assigned, sum in column above should be equal 1, if not assigned - 0. When sum equal 1 and values in columns are like 0.4 and 0.1, it means that request is assigned partly to few nodes. I want to count the COST caused dividing request into parts. For example - for request 2 (I mean in column 2) I have 0.4, 0.5, 0.1 on compute nodes 1,2,3 so I need to add to COST values from `compute_nodes_relation[1,2]`,`compute_nodes_relation[2,3]` and `compute_nodes_relation[1,3]`. In column 3 I have 0.5 and 0.5 on compute node 1 and 2  - now I need to add to COST value from `compute_nodes_relation[1,2]`. Column 4 - not divide into parts so I add nothing.

Comment: What is the best attempt you have so far?

Comment: @AmoRobb I tried to do something like that ```var float: Cost = (sum(m,m_2 in 1..num_compute_nodes, req in 1..num_request where (((assignment[m,request_loc[req],req] + assignment[m_2,request_loc[req],req])=10) /\ assignment[m,request_loc[req],req] != 10 /\ assignment[m_2,request_loc[req],req] !=10 /\ assignment[m,request_loc[req],req] != 0 /\ assignment[m_2,request_loc[req],req] !=0 /\ m != m_2) )(compute_nodes_relation_link[m, m_2]))/2;``` but ofcourse it only works when request is divided into 2 parts.

Answer (score 0):

`var float: transmission_cost_compute_nodes = sum( req in 1..num_request)(sum(m,m_2 in 1..num_compute_nodes where ((sum(m in 1.. num_compute_nodes)(assignment[m,request_loc[req],req])=10) /\ (sum(m_2 in 1.. num_compute_nodes)(assignment[m_2,request_loc[req],req])=10) /\ (assignment[m,request_loc[req],req] != 10) /\ (assignment[m_2,request_loc[req],req] !=10) /\ (assignment[m,request_loc[req],req] != 0) /\ (assignment[m_2,request_loc[req],req] !=0) /\ (m != m_2)))(compute_nodes_relation_link[m, m_2]))/2;`

I think that's the answer for my question.